# multiply/loop the object from an array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

In an array of object, I took the quantity value which is a number:

```
orders = [
    {itemId: '1', quantity: 2 }, // first order
    {itemId: '2', quantity: 3 }  // second order
]
```

Then pushed the object and will multiply from the quantity value

to multiply this:

```
let payingItem = orders.map({
    name: `item-${order.itemId}`,
    price: 20    
})
```

To have this:

```
// first order
    payingItem = 
    [
      { name: item-1, price: 20}, // 1
      { name: item-1, price: 20}  // 2
    ],
// second order
    payingItem = 
    [
      { name: item-2, price: 20}, // 1
      { name: item-2, price: 20}  // 2
      { name: item-2, price: 20}  // 2
    ],
```

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is.

Comment: So you want to create an array of arrays? Your final code block is invalid syntax, but would be valid if there were `[]` around the value to the right of the `=`.

Comment: I will try to figure things out then, thanks, guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const orders = [
        {itemId: '1', quantity: 2 }, // first order
        {itemId: '2', quantity: 3 }  // second order
    ]

 // Retrieve the result of map.

    const payingItems = orders.map(function(c,i){

  // Create a temp Array to save items as quantity exists.

        const payingItem = [];
        for (var index = 0; index < c.quantity; index++)  {
            payingItem.push({
                name: 'item-'+c.itemId,
                price: 20
            })
     }
       return payingItem
    });
    
    console.dir(payingItems);
```

Comment: Good basic answer! If you want to put a runnable version in your answer, [here's how to do it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: Thank you, this is a good answer, will try this at work, asap :D

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to convert your array of objects into an array of arrays, with the subarrays containing the number of objects defined by `quantity`.

If so, you're on the right track with `map`, but you need to pass it a function, and that function has to return the array of objects, something like this:

```js
const orders = [
    {itemId: '1', quantity: 2 }, // first order
    {itemId: '2', quantity: 3 }  // second order
];

// Map the orders to an array of arrays
const payingItems = orders.map(({itemId, quantity}) =>
    // Create this array by filling it in with as many
    // objects as `quantity` says it should have
    Array.from(Array(quantity), () => ({
        name: `item-${itemId}`, price: 20
    }))
);

console.log(payingItems);
```

That uses [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) passing in a function that creates and returns the subarrays by using `Array(quantity)` and then [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)'s mapping feature to create a new array from that containing the objects.

That version uses concise arrow functions which may slightly obscure the meaning, so here's the verbose arrow function version that does the same thing slightly more explicitly:

```js
const orders = [
    {itemId: '1', quantity: 2 }, // first order
    {itemId: '2', quantity: 3 }  // second order
];

// Map the orders to an array of arrays
const payingItems = orders.map(({itemId, quantity}) => {
    // Create this array by filling it in with as many
    // objects as `quantity` says it should have
    const subarray = Array.from(Array(quantity), () => {
        const obj = {name: `item-${itemId}`, price: 20};
        return obj;
    });
    return subarray;
});

console.log(payingItems);
```

Comment: You guys are awesome! thank you, will try this when I get to work asap